# Captcha check - Form is submitting to a server page I do not have access to

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, captcha, recaptcha

My client needs me to implement captcha on his form. The form's action is set to an external page, to which we do not have access.

I wanted to use Google's reCaptcha but it seems that piece of code (which does the checking) needs to be placed in the targed page (which we cannot access).

What is the solution? I tried with using some simple Javascript array and jQuery checking of the value but it seems that spammers after couple of months learned how to dig the values out of the page code (yes, the values are written there, it's javascript - and I do not know better way) because the spam is arriving again.

A good client-side way would be even better. If you know a script or some code to be used here it'd be very appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't send the form to your server first, and then post the form data to the 3rd party site using curl after checking the recaptcha

Comment: Well that might be an option but at the moment I don't know how to proceed with that. Do you think using cUrl, use the page as URL and supplying form data as a parameter or similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host another server with captcha and submit your form there. In case of success, submit the form from the captcha server to the one you don't have access to.

Comment: Then the above comment might be even simpler - submit to the same server which the form data is sent from? No need for intermediate server, right?

Comment: @developer10 There's no reason for an intermediate server to check the captcha. Simply change the target of the form `action` to your server, and save the URL in a variable server-side, post to it using cURL if the recaptcha is correct.

Comment: @developer10 I thought he doesn't have an access to it, no? Anyways, you get my point. Submit the data to where you check your captcha.

Comment: @Tengiz We have access to the starting website, how else could we put captcha there. But the form action is pointing to a page which is on another server, to which we cannot access (he can but only to his member area, not the core files). Thank you for your comments anyway, any help is appreciated.